# Cast Interface to its implementations

Tags: c#

I have an interface that is implemented by more classes that have additional information stored. And I need to be able to convert the implementations without explicitly saying that it is this one implementation.

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    Type GetType();
}

public class Dog : IAnimal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    Type GetType() {return typeof(Dog);}
    public int TimesBarked { get; set; }
}

public class Rhino : IAnimal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    Type GetType() {return typeof(Rhino);}
    public bool HasHorn { get; set; }
}
```

Through most of the code I use the interface with no problem but at some point I need to get the implementation casted in its original type.

```
IAnimal animal = new Dog
{
    Name = "Ben",
    TimesBarked = 30
}
// Doing stuff with Ben

// In some other function
AnotherObject.SomeMethodThatNeedsToKnowType(animal) //Needs to be Converted before putting here
```

I don't know which object I will get so I have to make something that can convert anything to its original type. 
Unfortunately `Convert.ChangeType(animal, animal.GetType())` returns `object{Dog}` not `Dog`. I can change the interface and its implementations but not the Method.

Comment: Just for the record; needing to do this is a big red flag.

Comment: Why do you have `GetType()` as part of your interface? `object` already includes this.

Comment: It defeats the purpose of an interface if you have to query each object to try to find out it's actual type...

Comment: This seems like an appropriate place for the Visitor pattern, with the `IAnimal` interface having a `void Accept(IAnimalVisitor visitor)` method, and your visitor implementations handling animal specific commands.

Comment: What happens if `animal` is not a `Dog` when you call `AnotherObject.SomeMethodThatNeedsToKnowType(animal)`? Throw? Do nothing? Convert it to `Dog` even though it is, say, `Cat`?

Comment: The `AnotherObject.SomeMethodThatNeedsToKnowType(animal)` will accept any animal that is in its original type.

Answer (score 5):

> I don't know which object I will get so I have to make something taht can convert anything to it's original type.

And what are you going to *do* with it at that point? Since you don't know the type, you don't know what methods you can call, etc. This is why your original solution returns an `object`.

You could use `dynamic` but if you try to use a method that doesn't exist that would just throw. The closest you'll get is simple `is` checks (C# 7 pattern matching for brevity):

```
if (animal is Dog dog) 
   //Do stuff with dog
else if (animal is Rhino rhino)
   // Do stuff with rhino
```

**Big fat disclaimer**: Downcasting is a huge red flag. Downcasting when you don't even know what type to expect is even worse. Your design almost certainly needs to be re-thought.

Comment: I am not going to do anything, the method knows to do with any `IAnimal`, but it needs to have it casted properly (and it is not mine and I cannot change it). To do a huge if else logic just to cast it is potentialy dangerous if anybody adds new  implementation to`IAnimal`.

Comment: @JanPokorný You are correct; which is why this whole thing is a mess. I can't advise further without more details; perhaps you need a follow-up question with more of the actual issue you are running into?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, what your end-game is. If you don't want to use IS and AS, I probably would though ... Anyhow:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public interface IAnimal
        {
            string Name { get; set; }
            //Type GetType();
        }

        public class Dog : IAnimal
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            //new Type GetType() { return typeof(Dog); }
            public int TimesBarked { get; set; }
        }

        public class Rhino : IAnimal
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            //new Type GetType() { return typeof(Rhino); }
            public bool HasHorn { get; set; }
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IAnimal animal1 = new Dog { Name = "Ben", TimesBarked = 30 };
            IAnimal animal2 = new Rhino { Name = "James" };

            MessageBox.Show($"GetType : {animal1.GetType()}");

            PeopleWillTellYouToNotDoThis(animal1);
            PeopleWillTellYouToNotDoThis(animal2);
        }

        private void PeopleWillTellYouToNotDoThis(dynamic inAnimal)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"GetType : {inAnimal.GetType()}");

            //The following works.  But, you should probably really use 'IS' to see if you have a RHINO or not
            try { MessageBox.Show($"HasHorn : {inAnimal.HasHorn}"); } catch { };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The brand-new C# feature, a "Pattern Matching" switch statement (look at [the Switch Statement docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch), near the bottom) can help you out.

I through together a quick interface and a couple of classes that implement it:

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    string Speak();
}

public class Cat : IAnimal
{
    public string Speak()
    {
        return "Meow";
    }
}

public class Dog : IAnimal
{
    public string Speak()
    {
        return "Woof";
    }
}
```

Then I created a collection of `IAnimal`s and used a `switch` statement to figure out what was what:

```
  var animals = new List<IAnimal>
  {
      new Cat(), new Dog(), new Cat()
  };

  foreach (var animal in animals)
  {
      switch (animal)
      {
          case Cat cat:
              Debug.WriteLine("This is a cat");
              break;
          case Dog dog:
              Debug.WriteLine("This is a dog");
              break;
      }
  }
```

The output from this looked like:

> This is a cat
>
> This is a dog
>
> This is a cat

I don't show it, but the `cat` and `dog` variables are perfectly good, well-typed object references that you can use while they are in scope.

But, as @BradleyDotNET mentioned, this is often a sign of a bad design or implementation.